# I have a problem with the navigation fragments in my proyect, it sais that I need a defaut nav host atribute but I already put it

Tags: android, kotlin

I am in a Android develepoment course and I am with the navigation with fragment and I put the defautnavhost on my unique fragment but it stil get an error

```
<fragment
                app:defautNavHost="true"
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation">
            </fragment>
```

This is the error:

```
Android resource linking failed
AndroidStudioProjects/andfun-kotlin-android-trivia-starter-code/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:24: AAPT: error: attribute defautNavHost (aka com.example.android.navigation:defautNavHost) not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a misspelling error:

```
app:defautNavHost="true"
```

change it to:

```
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```